# Tkinter bind mouse clicks to frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I must be missing something obvious, I have two frames in my Tkinter program, each with a bunch of labels in a grid layout. I want to bind the mouseclick to one of them but not the other. I currently use

```
root.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_function)
```

but that also triggers if I click in the other frame. I assumed that using

```
schedule_frame.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_function)
```

would work but then I get no response anywhere.

The function I am calling is:

```
def mouse_function(event):
    y = event.widget.grid_info()['row']
    x = event.widget.grid_info()['column'] 
    widgets[(y, x)].configure(state="active")
    shiftSelection(y,x)
```

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't the .bind() method work with a frame widget in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16923167/3357935)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you bind to the root window, that binding applies to all widgets in that root window. That is why it triggered for either frame. This is standard behavior for tkinter.

When you move the binding to the frame, it stopped working because the frame never saw the event. When you click on the label, it is the label that sees the binding, not the frame (unless you click in the space between labels)

There are at least three ways to solve this problem. One is that you can put the binding on the labels rather than the frame. Another is to keep the binding on the root window, but within the function check to see if the widget is a child of that one frame.

A third solution involves changing the bind tags for the labels. For an in depth example see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771893/7432

Comment: Thanks, this part worked, but now I can't get the order to function properly, I made a new question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33780668/where-to-put-event-handlers-and-pass-variables-to-it.