# Where to put event handlers and pass variables to it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to bind a mouseclick to a grid in a certain frame, after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741987/tkinter-bind-mouse-clicks-to-frame/33742699#33742699) I made a new class and bound the event to that, which works. But the function of the mouse event needs a variable that is made in the MainApp class, I can't get it to work properly. Depending on the arrangement either I can't get the `widgets` variable to be used in the function, or the order of functions/classes is wrong and thus the program won't find something because it is referenced too soon.

So my main question is how do I get the function working, which I think mostly involves where do I put that thing? As a function in the `Schedule_Label` class? as a function of the `MainApp`? A loose function? Is it smarter to put all the event handlers in a seperate Python file and import that?

Excluding some code this is what is happening:

```
class Schedule_Label(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_1)

...
class Schedule, this class uses Schedule_Label

class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        #class schedule is used here
        ...
        schedule_widgets = self.schedule.New(date, stafflist)
        ...

def mouse_1(event):
    r = event.widget.grid_info()['row']
    c = event.widget.grid_info()['column']
    schedule_widgets[(r,c)].configure(state="active")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApp(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Remove `self` from `mouse_1` (No `self.mouse_1` here `self.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_1)`)

Comment: That was left from when I put that function inside of the `Schedule_Label` class, I edited the question now. With this setup the problem is that it can't find the reference `schedule_widgets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `schedule_widgets` from `mouse_1`, which is in the namespace of `MainApp`, to be able to use it like that use `global` keyword.

```
schedule_widgets = None#--------------------------------------------------------  new ---

class Schedule_Label(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_1)

...
class Schedule, this class uses Schedule_Label

class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        global schedule_widgets #-----------------------------------------------  new ---
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        #class schedule is used here
        ...
        schedule_widgets = self.schedule.New(date, stafflist)
        ...

def mouse_1(event):
    global schedule_widgets #---------------------------------------------------  new ---
    r = event.widget.grid_info()['row']
    c = event.widget.grid_info()['column']
    schedule_widgets[(r,c)].configure(state="active")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApp(root)
app.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

There is another way to do it, but `schedule_widgets` should be an attribute of `MainApp` and when you instantiate `schedule_Label` you should give parent reference so that `mouse_1` can access `schedule_widgets` with parent reference

```
class Schedule_Label(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, p=parent: mouse_1(event, p)) # ---  new ---

...
class Schedule, this class uses Schedule_Label

class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        
        #class schedule is used here
        ...
        self.schedule_widgets = self.schedule.New(date, stafflist) #------------  new ---
        ...

def mouse_1(event, parent): #---------------------------------------------------  new ---
    r = event.widget.grid_info()['row']
    c = event.widget.grid_info()['column']
    parent.schedule_widgets[(r,c)].configure(state="active") #------------------  new ---
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApp(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```