# How to redirect mouse click/move/drag events from a custom grip Label to PanedWindow parent

Tags: python, tkinter, resize, mouseevent, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to add a nice handle to `Tkinter.PanedWindow` sash. To do that I `place` a `Label` with a custom grip image next to a pane. Example:

```python
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
pw = PanedWindow(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
l1 = Listbox(pw)
pw.add(l1)
l2 = Listbox(pw)
pw.add(l2)
pw.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

gripimg = PhotoImage(data="R0lGODlhBAAvAPEAALetnfXz7wAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAEAC8AAAIjRBwZwmKomjsqyVdXw/XSvn1RCFlk5pUaw42saL5qip6gnBUAOw==")
griplabel = Label(pw, image=gripimg)
griplabel.place(relx=1, rely=0.5, anchor=W, in_=l1)

root.mainloop()
```

It looks ok. But now the Label overlaps the sash, steals mouse events and I can't resize PanedWindow by dragging the Label. How can I make `griplabel` ignore mouse events and redirect them all to the PanedWindow sash?

I tried [bindtags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771893/7432), but:

```python
griplabel.bindtags(pw.bindtags())
```

does not seem to do anything, i.e. I still can't drag the Label to resize PanedWindow.

Or is there a better way to create a custom handle for PanedWindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a kind help of [#tcl freenode channel](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=tcl) I came up with this:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
pw = PanedWindow(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
l1 = Listbox(pw)
pw.add(l1)
l2 = Listbox(pw)
pw.add(l2)
pw.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

gripimg = PhotoImage(data="R0lGODlhBAAvAPEAALetnfXz7wAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAEAC8AAAIjRBwZwmKomjsqyVdXw/XSvn1RCFlk5pUaw42saL5qip6gnBUAOw==")
griplabel = Label(pw, image=gripimg, cursor="sb_h_double_arrow")
griplabel.place(relx=1, rely=0.5, anchor=W, in_=l1)

griplabel.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e:pw.event_generate("<Button-1>",x=e.x+griplabel.winfo_x(),y=e.y+griplabel.winfo_y()))
griplabel.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda e:pw.event_generate("<B1-Motion>",x=e.x+griplabel.winfo_x(),y=e.y+griplabel.winfo_y()))

root.mainloop()
```

Two `griplabel.bind(...)` calls forward mousedown+mousemove events from Label to PanedWindow, adjusting x and y coords. Those two events are enough to make the sash move.

And griplabel mouse "cursor" is set to `sb_h_double_arrow` as that's the cursor PanedWindow uses for sash by default, according to [the Tk documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/panedwindow.htm#M13):

> Command-Line Name: **-sashcursor**
>   Mouse cursor to use when over a sash. If null, **sb_h_double_arrow** will be used for horizontal panedwindows, and **sb_v_double_arrow** will be used for vertical panedwindows.

And it's also one of [cursor names recognized by Tk on all platforms](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/cursors.htm).

---

[TCL wiki mentions](https://wiki.tcl.tk/20058#pagetoc68f6b7b6) another way to set a custom sash handle bar, using `ttk.PanedWindow` with custom `ttk.Style` layout:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

gripimg = PhotoImage(data="R0lGODlhBAAvAPEAALetnfXz7wAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAEAC8AAAIjRBwZwmKomjsqyVdXw/XSvn1RCFlk5pUaw42saL5qip6gnBUAOw==")
style = ttk.Style()
style.element_create("Sash.xsash", "image", gripimg, sticky=W+E)
style.layout("MySash.TPanedWindow", [('Sash.xsash', {})])

pw = ttk.PanedWindow(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, style="MySash.TPanedWindow")
l1 = Listbox(pw)
pw.add(l1)
l2 = Listbox(pw)
pw.add(l2)
pw.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

But it looks and works differently. Essentially it replaces background of `ttk.PanedWindow` with a tiled image, which remains static, and the sash becomes a viewport sliding over it. That looks unusual, still someone may like it.